# Python multiplication table with while loops only

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, format

my task is to create a multiplication table looking like [this](http://gyazo.com/acf54336fe14033ffe536f74e42fffb0) where the user is asked to put in two numbers between 1 and 9. (in the picture the user put in "rows=3" "col=5").

I can't get my top row right, is it a way to make my code better?
"better" I mean like make the whole thing with only 2 while loops?

EDIT: I forgot to mention ONLY with WHILE loops, not with "for".

```
row=int(input("number of rows:"))
col=int(input("number of cols:"))
x=1
m=1
amount=col
while amount>0:
    print("%5d"%m, end="")
    m=m+1
    amount-=1
print()
while x<(row+1):
    y=1
    print(x, end="")
    while y<(col+1):
        print("%4d"%(x*y), end="")
        y=y+1
    print("\n")
    x=x+1
```

Comment: It might help respondants if you define what you been by 'make my code better'. Do you mean faster to execute? Do you need to fix a problem in functionality? Make it easier to read?

Comment: I was thinking that I could simplify the code somehow so instead of having "3" while loops I could use the one I have on the outside and nest it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juste manage all the table in heart of the loops. You can also have only one loop with a `while i*j <=row*col` if better is the minimum of loops. But for loop is the best solution for this problem.

```
row,col=3,5
i=0
while i <= row :
    j=0
    while j <= col:
        if i+j==0 : print('{:4s}'.format(''),end='') #corner
        elif i*j==0 : print('{:4d}'.format(i+j),end='') # border
        else : print('{:4d}'.format(i*j),end='') # table
        j=j+1   
    print()
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Stewart_R mentions in the comments, it's hard to tell what you are looking for -- but a cleaner way of printing a multiplication table would look like:

```
row,col = 3,5  # Test case

style = "{:3d}"

print "   ",
for j in range(1, col+1):
    print style.format(j),
print
for i in range(1, row+1):
    print style.format(i),
    for j in range(1,col+1):
        print style.format(i*j),
    print
```

Gives:

```
      1   2   3   4   5
  1   1   2   3   4   5
  2   2   4   6   8  10
  3   3   6   9  12  15
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I only want to use with while loops.

Comment: @Estonia_girl I understand that you are brand new to the site, but please try not to waste peoples time. If you can't articulate what you want in your original question, _we can't help you_. Please read the FAQ to the site.

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
for i in range(row+1):
    for j in range(col+1):
        print('{:4d}'.format(i*j if i*j>0 else i+j) if i+j>0 else '{:4s}'.format(''),end='')  
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
num=int(input("enter the table number=")
limit=int(input("enter the limit=")
while(i<=limit):
     result= num * i
     print( num ,"x",i,"=",result)
     i=i+1
input("press enter to exit")
```

Comment: It will be great if you could some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want any no of table run this code (Python code)

```
i=1
x=int(input("table() "))
while i<=10:
   print(i*x)
   i=i+1
```

For Example, want 12's table
Output
table(12)
12
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
108
120